# How do I find Safaris reading list?

Tags: finder, safari

I'm trying to use a new browser and I was used to saving my favorite sites on favorite and the blogs and sites I that interest me in the reading list for later reading.

Where are bookmarks and reading lists stored in the macOS system?

I'm using safari Version 16.4 and macOS Ventura 13.3.1

Answer (score 1):

> Where are bookmarks and reading lists stored in the macOS system?

They could be found at two different places, Safari and Finder. The most readable version of those lists will be in Safari.

---

### In Safari

In the Safari menu bar at the top of the screen, click on "View". From the dropdown menu, you will see options for your bookmarks and reading list:

- Click on "**Show Bookmarks Sidebar**" or press the <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>^ Control</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> (if using the ABC keyboard layout) keyboard shortcut to view your Bookmarks. ( <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>  <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> works too)
- Click on "**Show Reading List Sidebar**" or press the  <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>^ Control</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> keyboard shortcut to view your Reading List.

This will open a new window or sidebar where you can see and manage your Bookmarks and Reading List.

---

### In Finder

The Bookmarks are located in a plist file at `~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist` and the Reading List (in a folder) is at `~/Library/Safari/ReadingListArchives/`.